# OpenLDAP's cn=config add separate user for replication of “olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config”

Tags: openldap

I hope I'm not asking a dumb question. I'm new to creating my own LDAP service.

For my regular mdb database it's easy to add multiple administrators. Since it contains an `olcSuffix` attribute it's possible to add a new OU, add `olcAccess` rules and everything, so the replication can be configured to use a dedicated user.

But I haven't found a way to do something similar when replicating the config:

`olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config`

I can't add ou's to the `cn=config` dn. I receive the following error:

```
could not add entry dn="ou=admins,cn=config" (line=825)
```

Any recommendations?

---

UPDATE 20180828

Here I add more detail about what I've tried.

When I try to import, the server complains:

```
# ldapadd -c -x -H "ldap://localhost" -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W -f test.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "ou=admins_group,dc=config"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge

adding new entry "uid=u1,ou=admins_group,dc=config"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

The contents of test.ldif are:

```
dn: ou=admins_group,dc=config
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: admins_group

dn: uid=u1,ou=admins_group,dc=config
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: securityPrincipal
uid: u1
cn: u1
sAMAccountName: u1
objectSid: u1
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9VVN6MVpuRmx5bWVmN2w5Tmp5WmJtb3duKzMwSEtXREc=
shadowLastChange: 15969
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1300
gidNumber: 1300
homeDirectory: /home/admin/u1
```

Almost the same one I use to add users to the mdb database

Comment: Is there a return or reason code accompanying the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *specific* error means that there is no database with a matching prefix for your entries' DNs. Remember that the config backend uses `cn=config`, not `dc=config`. (dc would mean it's a DNS domain component which it is not.)

But even if you get the prefix right, you'll just receive a different error (schema violation). In the end, cn=config **cannot** have extraneous entries, this is enforced by the backend.

The good news is that the user account doesn't *have* to be under cn=config, it can be anywhere in *any* database. Neither syncrepl nor olcAccess rules care the slightest bit about what DN suffix your users have, so just add the account to your main mdb database – or reuse the existing one.

For example, this is my own configuration:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to dn.sub="cn=config"
  by dn="cn=Replica,ou=System,dc=example,dc=org" read
  by group="cn=Administrators,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=org" manage
  by * none break
...
```

As long as the user can log in to the server, you can list it in ACLs and use for replication. (Indeed, certificate or SASL/Kerberos logins may generate DNs which don't exist in the directory *at all*, and those are still perfectly usable.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It will be needed to add an `olcAccess` rule to permit read and write permissions in config for the specified user. Right?

Comment: Yes. Everything remains the same. (Although on a separate note, syncrepl is always pull-based so the replica user only needs 'read' permissions.)